# file.mkdirs() isn't working

Tags: java, android, file, io

Here's the code:

```
  String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AllAroundMe/Images";
      File file = new File(folderPath);
      if(!file.exists())
      {
            if(file.mkdirs());
            Log.d("MyTag","Created folders succefully");
      }
      if(file.exists())
      {
      Log.d("MyTag", "folders exists: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
      }
```

The second if never happens, and it should, because I make these dirs. What is wrong with my code?
BTW, everytime I run this program, it always goes in the first condition.

Comment: Note that `semi-colon` after your `if` condition.

Comment: the problem is just that `semi-colon` and than the message is not printed or the folders aren't created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your android.manifest file.

Also, it would be better to construct your `file` object like this:

```
String folderPath = "AllAroundMe/Images";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folderPath);
```

Comment: I haven't missed the premissions, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/ZM4WSdzh the log says: "FOLDERS NOT EXISTS" AND "didnt create" which means the folders aren't created.

Comment: @idish - Please check the availability of external storage, using the technique described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove that `semi-colon` after that inner if: -

```
if(file.mkdirs()) {
    Log.d("MyTag","Created folders succefully");
}
```

**P.S**: - That is why you should always use curly braces, even if you have only single statement if, so that you don't do such kind of mistakes.

Comment: Actually, `mkdirs` is the right method to call. It creates all necessary intermediate directories in the path.

Comment: Haha alright, that's true, but still why the second condition never happens, even though i fixed that?

Comment: @idish. Is your folder getting created? And you would like to look at Ted's answer. You might have missed that.

Comment: @RohitJain I haven't missed the premissions, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/ZM4WSdzh the log says: "FOLDERS NOT EXISTS" AND "didnt create" which means the folders aren't created.